# What is the efficient way to retrieve(select) data from database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, indexing

In my database contain about 2 millions rows. That contains collection of sentences in each rows(Not English language).

```
    ![Image of database][1]
```

[image]

As a example if user give 'abcd' ,that matched with both row 1,3. Therefor both should select.
Because of that huge time taken to data retrieve. I'm using following code to retrieve data. If any given word match with the database those rows should be select.

```
        sb.append("SELECT Sentence FROM corpus Where ");
         for(int k=0;k<wordList.size();k++){
             sb.append( " Sentence like '%" + wordList.get(k) + "%' OR ");
         } 
         sb.append(" 1=0");
         rs2 = dbc.sqlExecute(sb.toString());
```

That selection word may be anywhere in the row. That may be front or middle or end. My problem is when user give some word phrase, huge time taken to select matched rows. Is there any proper way to speed my database retrieves? I think indexing may not work because of I'm not searching only the starting point of the rows. That matched words may contain anywhere in the rows. What is the efficient way to do this? Huge time taken to retrieve. Huge problem to me.Can anyone know proper way to do this?

Comment: See FULLTEXT indexes, but note that slugs matching > 50% of the dataset will not be returned

Comment: @Strawberry is that work for other languages not for English? Do you have proper guide about that?

Comment: FULLTEXT supports most multibyte character sets. The exception is that for Unicode, the utf8 character set can be used, but not the ucs2 character set. See the manual.

Comment: @Strawberry Do you have guide or tutorial any links relate to that?" 50% of the dataset will not be returned " what's that mean?

Comment: Go to google. Type MySQL FULLTEXT. Press enter. Click on the first thing that appears. Avoid asking inane and alienating questions.

Comment: @Strawberry Ok thanx dear. I asked because I have very limited time to do all those things. Thanx I will search.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need for loop, just do like this:

```
sb.append("SELECT Sentence FROM corpus Where Sentence like '%");

sb.append(wordList);

sb.append("%'");
```

Comment: Is that efficient in searching? My query create very quickly. Problem remain in the go through the each row and select matched rows.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the efficient solution is to use a [`PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with a bind parameter and execute it in a loop. You could use a [`For-Each` Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html), and for each `word` in `wordList` bind the parameter and then get a [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (using a [`try-with-resources`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)) and add the returned `sentences` to your `List` with something like

```
List<String> sentences = new ArrayList<>();
String sql = "SELECT Sentence FROM corpus WHERE Sentence LIKE ?";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
try {
    ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    for (String word : wordList) {
        ps.setString(1, String.format("%%%s%%", word));
        try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
            sentences.add(rs.getString(1));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (ps != null) {
        try {
            ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

While a FULLTEXT index on the `Sentence` column is probably advisable, this method has the benefit using the query cache and reducing the size of your query. The `OR` clauses just muddy the situation, since you want the matching rows of any of them. You might also consider a `Set<String> sentences`.

Comment: The problem is MySQL's inability to use indexes on wild card searches where the wild card precedes the string. This solution does nothing to address that.

Comment: @Strawberry Edit added about FULLTEXT index, but without that you still get the advantage of the query cache (and you reduce the size of the query).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Is that means should I study about FULLTEXT index and add to my database?

Comment: @Maduri Take a look at [`CREATE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html)